# Civ 6: RnF emergency but where?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civ 6 Rise and Fall, a religious emergency has been declared and I am game but where is the city...? I can't find it :/ is there a UI feature leading me?

Answer (score 1):

The `Emergencies` should tell you the `Target City` within the card that appears. In the below image the `Target` is `St Petersburg` and the `Members` must prevent it from following the specified `Religion` for 16 turns.

There are essentially two scenarios that could need to be played out:

1. The city is currently following a different religion then the goal of the `Emergency`. Since this emergency will last for only 30 turns you need to change the religion within the city in at least 14 turns. Also if waiting for the last minute like that you must ensure that the religion does not swap back during the rest of the `Emergency`. Generally in this scenario the city has been flipped and you must flip it back.
2. The city is currently following the religion that is the goal of the `Emergency`. The strategy here is the opposite from above, the only goal is to keep the city following that religion for the first 16 turns, then the `Emergency` will have to end. Generally in this scenario a city has been flipped and you must prevent it from flipping back.

[image]

Note: I found this image during a Google search and I do not take credit for its creation.

Comment: Yeah, this is the definition of an emergency, thanks but my question was not that. Please read: "but where is the city...? I can't find it :/ is there a UI feature leading me?"

Comment: My apologies. Well there is no UI marker leading you to that city. However since the `Antarctic Late Summer Patch` a `Search` tool has been added to the game. So you could enter the city name within that tool and it should allow you to find the city that way. 

I think this might be limited to tiles that you have seen at one point or another, but I would have to confirm that limitation through some tests. However you would not have had to see the city for sure, just the tile that is below it. I use the feature to find all of the uranium on the map after it is discovered.

Does this help?